# JavaFX -- ChangeLisener Issues and Opening Scene From Within a Scene

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm writing to get some information regarding JavaFX. I have designed an application using SceneBuilder that has a primary scene consisting of a few text fields and buttons used to browse for files. There is also a text area used for output once the program has been run. I have added change listeners within the initialize method of the Controller so that when the output text area is updated a log file gets modified.

Initially I tested this using the output text area to display the log file. I was able to get everything working correctly with it logging and displaying the log in this output text area once I select a 'view log' menu item from the main File menu. I ran into an issue that didn't seem very cleanly solved where when I displayed the Log it wanted to also log that display. I couldn't think of a clean work around for this and decided I would rather have the log open in its own secondary popup scene.

One of my issues is that if I place a change listener on the output text area inside the Controller's initialize method, when I try to 'view log' it throws a null pointer exception and points me to the line where the change listener is added. But please note that although it throws this exception trying to open the log window the change listeners and output text area still work appropriately.

If I remove the change listener the window opens fine - but nothing is updated within the logFileOutputTextArea.

Controller File:

```
public class AppController implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    private TextArea logFileOutputTextArea;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {


        verifierOutputTextArea.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String t, String t1)
            {
                // IF we have a valid file
                if (verifierOutputTextArea.textProperty().getValue().equals("Valid"))
                {
                  openOutputFolderButton.visibleProperty().setValue(!openOutputFolderButton.visibleProperty()
                        .getValue());
                }

            }
        });


        verifierOutputTextArea.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String t, String t1)
            {
                appendLog(verifierOutputTextArea.textProperty().getValue());    // append the output to the log

            }
        });

        // Check for a preset input file location
        checkDefaultInputDirectory();

    } // END INITIALIZE


    @FXML
    private void openLog()
    {

        try
        {
            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/logwindow.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            dialogStage.setScene(scene);
            dialogStage.setTitle("Log");
            dialogStage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        Path logFilePath = Paths.get(StaticTools.LOG_FILE_LOCATION);



        // IF the file doesn't exist
        if (!Files.exists(logFilePath))
        {
            this.logFileOutputTextArea.textProperty().setValue("Log has not been created yet!");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] fileByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(logFilePath);

                this.logFileOutputTextArea.setText(StaticTools.cryptTool(new String(fileByteArray), Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE));


            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } // END OPENLOG

} // END CONTROLLER
```

Log Window .fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="304.0"
        prefWidth="478.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
      fx:controller="application.javafx.AppController">
    <children>
        <GridPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="22.0" prefHeight="269.0" prefWidth="446.0">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
            </rowConstraints>
            <children>
                <Label text="Log File">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>
                <TextArea fx:id="logFileOutputTextArea" editable="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"
                          wrapText="true" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
            </children>
        </GridPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Do I need a separate controller for each fxml file? Why does placing initialize statements and change listeners into the initialize method cause issues? Why after the output text area in the main scene has been modified, either by clearing the text or setting the text, does alt-tabbing to a different window throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch` exceptions every time?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you show the code that declares the text area?

Comment: James_D: Please see the edits, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use one controller class for two different fxml files: LogWindow.fxml and some other fxml file which invokes `showLog()` by means of an event handler on a menu item.

If this is the case, you are going to end up with two instances of the controller: one created by the `FXMLLoader` that loads the "main" fxml, and one created by the `FXMLLoader` that loads LogWindow.fxml. The `showLog()` method is being invoked on the instance created by the "main" fxml, so it will populate the text area defined in the "main" fxml (if there is one, else you will likely get a null pointer exception). This of course is not the text area in LogWindow.fxml, so the text will not be displayed there.

You probably want to create a separate controller class for LogWindow.fxml, and populate the text area in its `initialize()` method.

Comment: James, in the process of updating my question I didn't see your response. I am going to try your suggestion and see if it remedies the one issue. - thanks!

Comment: James, excellent! That solved the issue I was having with the log window. Do you happen to have an idea about the alt-tab issue? 

If I need to re-post the question separately I can do that as well.

Comment: Sounds like a different question... please post it separately.